# Problem with "addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller". Endpoints not found

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a helm chart which I use to deploy my service in AKS. When I deploy the objects in AKS, I could see in the log of ingress controller pod that it seems that there isn't created any endpoint for my service, but that's not true because I can see the endpoints in the cluster. I could see **Service "mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-svc" does not have any active Endpoint**

Could anyone help me? Thank you!!

The information is here

Output of `helm install myservice --dry-run --debug./myfirst-backend-project/ --values values.yaml`

```
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/namespace.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: mynamespace
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
---
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myprojectname-mynamespace-secrets
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: Opaque
stringData:
  application-secrets.yml: |-
    my-property:
      secrets: my value
---
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myprojectname-mynamespace-configmap
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  application-configmap.yml: |-
    my-property:
      configmap: my value
---
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myprojectname-mynamespace-svc
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
---
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myprojectname-mynamespace-depl
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: myfirst-backend-project
          env:
            - name: "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
              value: "-Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/opt/conf/ -Dspring.profiles.active=configmap,secrets -Dlogging.path=/opt/logs/ -Dspring.application.name=myprojectname-mynamespace"
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "mytestcontainerregistry2021.azurecr.io/samples/democicd:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
              port: http
          volumeMounts:
          - name: configmap-volume
            mountPath: /opt/conf/application-configmap.yml
            subPath: application-configmap.yml
            readOnly: true
          - name: secrets-volume
            mountPath: /opt/conf/application-secrets.yml
            subPath: application-secrets.yml
            readOnly: true
          resources:
            {}
      volumes:
        - name: configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: myprojectname-mynamespace-configmap
        - name: secrets-volume
          secret:
            secretName: myprojectname-mynamespace-secrets
---
# Source: myfirst-backend-project/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myprojectname-mynamespace-ing
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myfirst-backend-project-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myprojectname-mynamespace
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myprojectname-mynamespace.b36c8e3faf88_omitedsomedigits.southcentralus.aksapp.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myprojectname-mynamespace-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Output of `kubectl get endpoints,pod,svc,deployment,ing -n mynamespace`

```
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME                                      ENDPOINTS                           AGE
endpoints/myprojectname-mynamespace-svc   10.244.0.78:8080,10.244.0.79:8080   60s

NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/myprojectname-mynamespace-depl-7dcc556694-5mhpg   1/1     Running   0          60s
pod/myprojectname-mynamespace-depl-7dcc556694-9s69b   1/1     Running   0          60s

NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
service/myprojectname-mynamespace-svc   LoadBalancer   10.0.232.21   20.xxx.xx.211   80:31568/TCP   60s

NAME                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/myprojectname-mynamespace-depl   2/2     2            2           60s

NAME                                               CLASS    HOSTS                                                                     ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress.extensions/myprojectname-mynamespace-ing   <none>   myprojectname-mynamespace.b36c8e3faf88_omitedsomedigits.southcentralus.aksapp.io             80      60s
```

Output of `kubectl logs -f deploy/addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller -n kube-system`

```
I0628 10:12:37.364322       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"mynamespace", Name:"myprojectname-mynamespace-ing", UID:"7fb9afb2-54f3-4db0-946f-a2a550d1ef0f", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"2446896", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-ing
W0628 10:12:40.478712       7 controller.go:806] Service "mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-svc" does not have any active Endpoint.
I0628 10:12:40.479110       7 controller.go:171] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0628 10:12:40.746868       7 controller.go:187] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0628 10:12:40.749870       7 controller.go:204] Dynamic reconfiguration succeeded.
W0628 10:12:43.807850       7 controller.go:806] Service "mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-svc" does not have any active Endpoint.
I0628 10:12:52.916374       7 controller.go:171] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0628 10:12:53.025489       7 controller.go:187] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0628 10:12:53.031179       7 controller.go:204] Dynamic reconfiguration succeeded.
I0628 10:12:57.043830       7 controller.go:169] Changes handled by the dynamic configuration, skipping backend reload.
I0628 10:12:57.056112       7 controller.go:204] Dynamic reconfiguration succeeded.
```

Comment: Sometimes, I could see the same lines followed by:

I0625 11:02:07.740192       7 status.go:362] updating Ingress mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-ing status to [{20.XXX.XXX.252 }]
I0625 11:02:07.746967       7 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"mynamespace", Name:"myprojectname-mynamespace-ing", UID:"d505f078-a58a-47de-90c0-2c296154f725", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1824053", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress mynamespace/myprojectname-mynamespace-ing

Comment: Which version of nginx ingress controller are you using?

Comment: ingress controller is a piece managed by azure, I'm not really sure what it is